# Where to find nice diagrams of trees and other graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, examples, co.combinatorics

Are there some publicly available, vector format diagrams of trees and other graphs?  They aren't hard to make, but they sure do take a lot of time (for me).

Comment: What do you want them for? If you just want some examples of graphs for personal use, Mathworld and Wikipedia pages have a number of them. 

Comment: Closed, not about mathematics.

Comment: Still don't understand why this was closed. There are plenty of popular questions about typesetting and making diagrams. These seem relevant to mathematical writing.

E.g. http://mathoverflow.net/questions/15664/what-is-the-best-graph-editor-to-use-in-your-articles

Comment: And http://mathoverflow.net/questions/55200/good-programs-for-drawing-graphs-directed-weighted-graphs

Answer (score 2):

use the LaTeX package [TikZ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PGF/TikZ). Here are some [examples](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/).

Answer (score 0):

[Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) has several [examples](http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery.php).

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia and Wikimedia Commons.